# Convert image sequence into 3d volume dataset .raw file C++

Tags: c++

I have converted an image sequences into .raw file for volume rendering purpose using ImageJ.

I have tried open the .raw file using text editor like notepad++, and try to look for the file structure but unfortunately, it has no header thus raw file and all the data is in binary format.

Thus, is there any way to convert the image sequence by writing out a tool in c++ as i cant managed to found .raw file specification for volume dataset.

Comment: Are you trying to create some sort of reader that requires you to know the organization of the file structure? Or would it be enough to just open it with a library like [Bio-Formats](http://imagej.net/Bio-Formats) to expose the metadata of your dataset?

Comment: @hinerm, I am trying to create a similar tool in c++ to convert image sequences into volume dataset .raw file

Comment: @hinerm, so it is actually a writer which writes those image sequence into a raw file but i dont know exactly the file structure of .raw volume dataset.